# Extract data from text file using Python (or any language)

Tags: python, data-extraction

I have a text file that looks like:

```
First Name  Bob 
Last name   Smith
Phone   555-555-5555    
Email   bob@bob.com
Date of Birth   11/02/1986  
Preferred Method of Contact Text Message    
Desired Appointment Date    04/29   
Desired Appointment Time    10am    
City    Pittsburgh  
Location    State
IP Address  x.x.x.x
User-Agent (Browser/OS) Apple Safari 14.0.3 / OS X  
Referrer    http://www.example.com  

First Name  john    
Last name   Smith
Phone   555-555-4444
Email   john@gmail.com
Date of Birth   03/02/1955
Preferred Method of Contact Text Message    
Desired Appointment Date    05/22
Desired Appointment Time    9am 
City    Pittsburgh  
Location    State
IP Address  x.x.x.x
User-Agent (Browser/OS) Apple Safari 14.0.3 / OS X  
Referrer    http://www.example.com 

.... and so on
```

I need to extract each entry to a csv file, so the data should look like: first name, last name, phone, email, etc. I don't even know where to start on something like this.

Comment: What is the separator between keys (First Name) and values (Bob)? Multiple whitespaces, tabulation?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you'll need to open the text file in read mode.
I'd suggest using a context manager like so:

```py
with open('path/to/your/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
       # do something with the line (it is a string)
```

as for managing the info you could build some intermediate structure, for example a dictionary or a list of dictionaries, and then translate that into a CSV file with the csv module.

you could for example split the file whenever there is a blank line, maybe like this:

```py
with open('Downloads/test.txt', 'r') as f:
     my_list = list() # this will be the final list
     entry = dict()   # this contains each user info as a dict
     for line in f.readlines():
         if line.strip() == "":  # if line is empty start a new dict
             my_list.append(entry) # and append the old one to the list
             entry = dict()
         else:                   # otherwise split the line and create new dict
             line_items = line.split(r'  ')
             print(line_items)
             entry[line_items[0]] = line_items[1]
 
 print(my_list)
```

this code won't work because your text is not formatted in a consistent way: you need to find a way to make the split between "title" and "content" (like "first name" and "bob") in a consistent way. I suggest maybe looking at [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and fixing the txt file by making spacing more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the data resides in a:

```
a="""
First Name  Bob
Last name   Smith
Phone   555-555-5555
Email   bob@bob.com
Date of Birth   11/02/1986
Preferred Method of Contact Text Message
Desired Appointment Date    04/29
Desired Appointment Time    10am
City    Pittsburgh
Location    State
IP Address  x.x.x.x
User-Agent (Browser/OS) Apple Safari 14.0.3 / OS X
Referrer    http://www.example.com

First Name  john
Last name   Smith
Phone   555-555-4444
Email   john@gmail.com
Date of Birth   03/02/1955
Preferred Method of Contact Text Message
Desired Appointment Date    05/22
Desired Appointment Time    9am
City    Pittsburgh
Location    State
IP Address  x.x.x.x
User-Agent (Browser/OS) Apple Safari 14.0.3 / OS X
Referrer    http://www.example.com
"""
line_sep = "\n" # CHANGE ME ACCORDING TO DATA
fields = ["First Name", "Last name", "Phone",
          "Email", "Date of Birth", "Preferred Method of Contact",
          "Desired Appointment Date", "Desired Appointment Time",
          "City", "Location", "IP Address", "User-Agent","Referrer"]
records = a.split(line_sep * 2)
all_records = []
for record in records:
    splitted_record = record.split(line_sep)
    one_record = {}
    csv_record = []
    for f in fields:
        found = False
        for one_field in splitted_record:
            if one_field.startswith(f):
                data = one_field[len(f):].strip()
                one_record[f] = data
                csv_record.append(data)
                found = True
        if not found:
            csv_record.append("")
    all_records.append(";".join(csv_record))
```

`one_record` will have the record as dictionary and `csv_record` will have it as a list of fields (ordered as `fields` variable)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to add: ignore this answer, the code from Koko Jumbo looks infinitely more sensible and actually gives you a CVS file at the end of it! It was a fun exercise though :)**

Just to expand on fcagnola's code a bit.

If it's a quick and dirty one-off, and you know that the data will be consistently presented, the following should work to create a list of dictionaries with the correct key/value pairing. Each line is processed by splitting the line and comparing the line number (reset to 0 with each new dict) against an array of values that represent where the boundary between key and value falls.

For example, "First Name  Bob" becomes ["First","Name","Bob"]. The function has been told that linenumber= 0 so it checks entries[linenumber] to get the value "2", which it uses to join the key name (items 0 & 1) and then join the data (items 2 onwards). The end result is ["First Name", "Bob"] which is then added to the dictionary.

```
class Extract:
    def extractEntry(self,linedata,lineindex):
        # Hardcoded list! The quick and dirty part.
        # This is specific to the example data provided. The entries
        # represent the index to be used when splitting the string
        # between the key and the data
        entries = (2,2,1,1,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,2,1)
        return self.createNewEntry(linedata,entries[lineindex])

    def createNewEntry(self,linedata,dataindex):
        list_data = linedata.split()
        key = " ".join(list_data[:dataindex])
        data = " ".join(list_data[dataindex:])
        return [key,data]                                              


with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_list = list() # this will be the final list
    entry = dict()   # this contains each user info as a dict
    extr = Extract() # class for splitting the entries into key/value
    x = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip() == "":    # if line is empty start a new dict
            my_list.append(entry) # and append the old one to the list
            entry = dict()
            x = 0
        else:                     # otherwise split the line and create new dict
            extracted_data = extr.extractEntry(line,x)
            entry[extracted_data[0]] = extracted_data[1]
            x += 1
    my_list.append(entry)

    print(my_list)
```